# Source model "" not found for attribute "industry"

Tags: customer, eav, customer-attribute

created an install script to add two fields to customer using the script below.

But I get this error.

```
Source model "" not found for attribute "industry"
```

My installer is

```
    $installer = $this;

    $installer->startSetup();

    $this->addAttribute('customer_address', 'industry', array(
    'type' => 'int',
    'input' => 'select',
    'label' => 'Industry',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'visible_on_front' => 1,
    'source'=>'address/entity_resourse',
    'option'=> array(
    'values' => array(
                0 => 'College & University',
                1 => 'Hotel & Motels',
                2 => 'Small/Medium Bussiness',
                3 => 'Correctional Facilities',
                4 => 'Goverment/NPOs',
                5 => 'Retail Security',
                6 => 'Homeowness',
                7 => 'Other',
            ),
        ),
    ));


$this->addAttribute('customer_address', 'resourse', array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'input' => 'text',
    'label' => 'How you heard about us?',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'visible_on_front' => 1
)); 
Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute('customer_address', 'industry')
    ->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer','customer_account_create','customer_account_edit','adminhtml_checkout'))
    ->save();
/*
if (version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.6.0', '<='))
{
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
    $attrSetId = $customer->getResource()->getEntityType()->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
    $this->addAttributeToSet('customer_address', $attrSetId, 'General', 'industry');
}
*/
if (version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.6.0', '<='))
{
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
    $attrSetId = $customer->getResource()->getEntityType()->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
    $this->addAttributeToSet('customer_address', $attrSetId, 'General', 'resourse');
}
/*
if (version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.4.2', '>='))
{
    Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute('customer_address', 'industry')
    ->setData('used_in_forms', array('customer_register_address','customer_address_edit','adminhtml_customer_address'))
    ->save();
}
*/
if (version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.4.2', '>='))
{
    Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute('customer_address', 'resourse')
    ->setData('used_in_forms', array('customer_register_address','customer_address_edit','adminhtml_customer_address'))
    ->save();
}

$tablequote = $this->getTable('sales/quote_address');
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE  $tablequote ADD  `industry` varchar(255) NOT NULL"); 

$tablequote = $this->getTable('sales/quote_address');
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE  $tablequote ADD  `resourse` varchar(255) NOT NULL"); 


$tablequote = $this->getTable('sales/order_address');
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE  $tablequote ADD  `industry` varchar(255) NOT NULL");

$tablequote = $this->getTable('sales/order_address');
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE  $tablequote ADD  `resourse` varchar(255) NOT NULL");

$installer->endSetup();
```

**resourse.php**

```
        class Excellence_Address_Model_Entity_Resourse extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract

    { 
        public function getAllOptions()
        {
        if (!$this->_options) {
        $this->_options = array(
        array(
            'value' => '',
            'label' => '',
        ),
        array(
            'value' => '0',
            'label' => 'College & University',
        ),
        array(
            'value' => '1',
            'label' => 'Hotel & Motels',
        ),
        array(
            'value' => '2',
            'label' => 'Small/Medium Bussiness',
        ),
        array(
            'value' => '3',
            'label' => 'Correctional Facilities',
        ),
        array(
            'value' => '4',
            'label' => 'Goverment/NPOs',
        ),
        array(
            'value' => '5',
            'label' => 'Retail Security',
        ),
        array(
            'value' => '6',
            'label' => 'Homeowness',
        ),
        array(
            'value' => '7',
            'label' => 'Other',
        )

        );
        }
   }
```

**config.xml**

```
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <config>
            <modules>
                <Excellence_Address>
                    <version>0.2.0</version>
                </Excellence_Address>
            </modules>
            <frontend>
                <routers>
                    <address>
                        <use>standard</use>
                        <args>
                            <module>Excellence_Address</module>
                            <frontName>address</frontName>
                        </args>
                    </address>
                </routers>
                <layout>
                    <updates>
                        <address>
                            <file>address.xml</file>
                        </address>
                    </updates>
                </layout>
            </frontend>
            <global>
                <models>
                    <address>
                        <class>Excellence_Address_Model</class>
                        <resourceModel>address_mysql4</resourceModel>
                    </address>
                    <address_mysql4>
                        <class>Excellence_Address_Model_Mysql4</class>
                        <entities>
                            <address>
                                <table>address</table>
                            </address>
                        </entities>
                    </address_mysql4>
                </models>
                <resources>
                    <address_setup>
                        <setup>
                            <module>Excellence_Address</module>
                            <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                        </setup>
                        <connection>
                            <use>core_setup</use>
                        </connection>
                    </address_setup>
                    <address_write>
                        <connection>
                            <use>core_write</use>
                        </connection>
                    </address_write>
                    <address_read>
                        <connection>
                            <use>core_read</use>
                        </connection>
                    </address_read>
                </resources>
                <blocks>
                    <address>
                        <class>Excellence_Address_Block</class>
                    </address>
                </blocks>
                <helpers>
                    <address>
                        <class>Excellence_Address_Helper</class>
                    </address>
                </helpers>
             </global>
             <global>
                <fieldsets>
                    <sales_convert_quote_address>
                        <industry>
                            <to_order_address>*</to_order_address>
                            <to_customer_address>*</to_customer_address>
                        </industry>
                        <resourse>
                            <to_order_address>*</to_order_address>
                            <to_customer_address>*</to_customer_address>
                        </resourse>
                    </sales_convert_quote_address>
                    <customer_address>
                        <industry>
                            <to_quote_address>*</to_quote_address>
                        </industry>
                        <resourse>
                            <to_quote_address>*</to_quote_address>
                        </resourse>
                    </customer_address>
                </fieldsets>
            </global>
        </config>
```

I have also spend many hours, What is the best way to find the error?? Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

Your `industry` attribute is of type `select`. Hence Magento looking for source file that is using to render the options of this select attribute. So you need to specify this source file using the property `source`. It seems that you have already set that file `'source'=>'address/entity_resourse',` for industry attribute.

Now Magento will look for this file in `app/code/local (or community)/Younamespace/Yormodule/Model/entity/Resource.php`. I think you didnt created that file. It's content should look like

```
class Yournamespace_Yourmodule_Model_Entity_Resource 
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        //this method returns an array which will use to render option of your attribute
    }
}
```

Comment: **programmer_rkt** , Please see the above. I has update of my question.

Comment: @Supravat : can you show your config file of your module ?

Comment: **programmer_rkt** , I had update config.xml file.

Comment: your files look ok for me. are you sure you have source model file name `Resource.php` ?

Comment: try to use `$installer` instead of `$this` at `addAttribute` section

Comment: do you have `getDefaultEntities()` method in your setup resource file ?